# Upload jar executable to Azure and running

Tags: java, azure, jar

I have an application developed in java.
I have exported it to an executable jar and I would like to upload it to azure so that it runs with a certain schedule.
Until now it has been impossible for me to know how it is done.
I have done a web service with eclipse and if it is easy to deploy it in azure and make it work but not executable.
Can someone tell me how it is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run an executable jar file with a time trigger on Azure. The simple way is to deploy your jar file as a WebJob on Azure WebApp. Here is the steps to do it as below.

1. Create a `.bat` file named `run.bat` and write the follow commands as below.

   ```
   set JAVA_HOME=D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
   set CLASSPATH=.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib
   set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
   java -jar <your jar file name>.jar
   ```
2. Compress the `run.bat` file and your jar file to a zip file, then to deploy it with `Scheduled` trigger and a `CRON Expression` value on Azure portal.

   [image]

Then, you can start it on Azure portal, and to see the running logs via `Logs` button.

Note: for more information about `CRON Expression` or others, please see the section [`CRON expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#cron-expressions) of the offical tutorial `Run Background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service`.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierBonilloPonce If it helps, could you mark it as answer? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Microsoft desperately needs to find this post and add it to their Java examples page, since right now that page only has a war example.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, i think your project missing a `web.config` which should be deployed at the `wwwroot` path.

Here is a sample web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\ROOT.jar&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And make sure upload your jar file to `home\site\wwwroot\bin` folder. Further more information you could refer to this doc:[Running java jar file to serve web requests on Azure App Service Web Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/12/28/running-java-jar-file-to-serve-web-requests-on-azure-app-service-web-apps/).